# What does MySQL converting varchar to char?

Tags: mysql, char, varchar, alter-table, alter

When we add a new table, we made a mistake : a field was a varchar(255), but we have to write join queries.
So we alter table to make a char(6).

My question is : what does MySQL in this case ?
It trims right ?

Comment: why would you join on a char field. Better use an integer one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than worry about what MySQL does or doesn't do why not just convert the data yourself before the change.

e.g.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourField = LEFT(YourField,6);

ALTER TABLE YourTable MODIFY COLUMN YourField Char(6)
```

You should note that if your column data is too long it won't let you do the alter assuming  enable strict SQL mode see Shef's complete answer

Answer (score 1):

It will try to convert the format. In your case, the column is a string type, so it will truncate the value, if the strict SQL mode is not enabled.

> When you change a data type using CHANGE or MODIFY, MySQL tries to
>   convert existing column values to the new type as well as possible.
>
> Warning This conversion may result in alteration of data. For example,
>   if you shorten a string column, values may be truncated. To prevent
>   the operation from succeeding if conversions to the new data type
>   would result in loss of data, enable strict SQL mode before using
>   ALTER TABLE (see Section 5.1.6, “Server SQL Modes”).

Read the fine [warning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) down two fifth of the page.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL won't even let you alter the table if there's any case you'll lose data (e.g. a row has an entry where the field's text is longer than six characters), so you're better off converting the data how you see fit.